# How to assign dynamic id to views in Android?

Tags: android, dynamic

I am creating a dynamic TableLayout and TableRows which contains view like ImageView ,TextView.I am assging them id using setId() method.

As id I use a int variable and increment it to assign it as view id and also stores in an int array or list.And latter I use array or list to identify them in event handlers.

I just want to know is it right way (or problmatic) to assign id like this or is there any better way.

for eg

Variables

```
final int CHECK_BUTTON_ID = 982301;
int ids_check[];
```

in loop I create views and set ids.

```
Button btn_check = new Button(this);
int id = i + CHECK_BUTTON_ID;
btn_check.setId(id);
ids_check[i] = id;
```

Comment: it wil work unless u hav to delete some of the dynamically created table rows

Comment: i used the same ..i don't have any problems.. but i m not sure whether its correct... any way gud post

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IDs that get generated by Android's resource compiler, you'll see they're all 0x7f000000 or higher.  (Just highlight any R.id.id_name in Eclipse and press F3 to see for yourself.)

So if you dynamically generate IDs with your view, just use a lower range than that and you should be fine.